# jQuery: find siblings under varying depth

Tags: jquery, dom

Given a list of elements, I want to find all siblings sometimes buried deep. http://jsfiddle.net/4kuNS/
for the second list, I want to highlight all the list items but `nextAll()` shoots past the ones buried inside the `div` and `span` elements.

I want to know the best way to find all sibling elements by tagname, regardless of whether they are buried inside other elements. Realistically, I am looking for a sibling sets of descendants.

Note: I have no control over the HTML, and it needs to accomplish the task of discovering siblings given an element.

Comment: your markup is invalid as you have span as child of ul

Comment: `<span><div><li>` is invalid HTML structuring. I see what you mean, but valid DOM helps

Comment: @ArunPJohny I think you mean `li` as a child of `span`.

Comment: @DACrosby lol either way it's jacked

Comment: @DACrosby man, you're gonna confused this guy lol

Comment: @leo Nah, I'm sure he gets it. Or I really don't.. one of the two :)

Comment: it was a quick example I wrote, I'm sorry that it doesn't meet your level of quality, but I'm dealing with a case where the HTML is often dirty and invalid and have no control over it.

Comment: @KimJongWoo It's not at all that it doesn't meet my (or our) standards of coding - it's that it doesn't meet web standards and more importantly web browsers' coding quality. Invalid code leads to numerous browser display issues and DOM traveling like you're trying to do becomes buggy in the best of browsers with the best programmers. I understand not being able to do anything about it and I assure you no offence was directed at you personally - just whoever wrote the code. You can direct offence at him/her too;)

Answer (score 2):

To find all siblings of an element regardless of where they are located inside the element hierarchy you can use [jQuery.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

You can pass a css selector to the `find` method if you are only interested in a subset of the child elements. But, as already stated in the comments, make sure your markup is valid...in the JS Fiddler you've provided you have `span` tags nested inside a `ul` list which is invalid html

With `jQuery.find` you can do something like...

```
$('ul').find('span');
```

or

```
$('ul').find('li');
```

You can tailor the selectors your specific needs

Comment: the thing is this requires you to know the parent that contains all the items ahead of time. What I am looking for given an leaf node, find all nodes like it (which may have the similar set of ancestors with one common ancestor at the top).

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you want to achieve. In the JS Fiddler provided you HAVE to know the parent, what is it exactly you want to achieve in your second list? Highlight all the `li` items? like this? http://jsfiddle.net/4kuNS/3/

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471060/given-a-leaf-node-find-all-similar-nodes-like-it

Answer (score -1):

How about a simple

```
$("li")...
```

Selects all `li` tags at all levels. Do something like `$("#list1 li")` to narrow it down to list items from one list.

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/4kuNS/1/