# Given a leaf node, find the common parent that contains that leaf node tags

Tags: jquery, dom

```
<div id='parent'>

  <div>
     <span>
       <a>item1</a>
     </span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span>
      <span>
        <a>item2</a>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span>
      <a>item3</a>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a>item4</a>
            </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

given `$('a').eq(1)` find the common parent that contains `a`. you can't start at $('#parent'), it has to start from the starting leaf node and traverse up and somehow discover all the other leaf node (anchors) like it.

I have no control over the HTML, and need a way to automatically discover similar leaf nodes like the one I select.

Comment: Like it in what way? Same href (it doesn't have one)? Same class (hmm, no class, either)?

Comment: So start at the second anchor (eq is zero based) and traverse up (???) and find all other anchors with the same ... text maybe? There are none !

Comment: the leaf node are similar when they have the same tag and share one common parent.

Comment: None of the `<a>` elements in your example have common parents. The first three are children of different `<span>` elements, and the last one's parent is a `<div>` that has no other children.

Comment: If you can figure out how to describe what you mean precisely, you shouldn't have any problem finding the jQuery DOM traversal functions to implement it. But if you can't describe the criteria, you obviously can't implement it, or expect us to figure it out, either.

Comment: the common parent would be `div` for all the item anchors

Comment: @KimJongWoo The problem I see is that the "common parent" for each of your anchors is at a different level above the anchor. The first one has a span in between, the second has 2 spans, the third has half a span tag.. The common parent you see is obvious in this example (`#parent`) but if you duplicate this code 10x and ask which element is the common parent of each anchor, the answer is `body`. Without some sort of qualifier of "these links are related", the most reasonable parent is `body`. No DOM traveling needed, but I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: Now, for example, if all of the parent divs had a consistent class name (`.iIsParent` or what have you), you could go from anchor to 'parent with the class name' and from there find all anchors in the parent (even exclude the one you started at if you want). But without some sort of "use this element as a parent" there's no consistent way to find said parent element with such inconsistent HTML that I (or anyone in the couple identical questions you've asked) knows of. You're probably going to need to modify the HTML output.

Comment: @DACrosby You are not understanding the scope of the problem, it is not limited to this example, this is a snippet of the possible data set I am dealing with, and I am looking for a tree searching algorithm that can discover similiar elements based on the common parent. The common parent won't be the body because it would consist of so many other 'a' on the page. This is why I stated that it can't start from a top down approach, it has to start searching for hte common parent by starting from the bottom.

Comment: @KimJongWoo Yep, that's the issue I mentioned. So, please explain in more detail what  exactly sets off the "common parent" as the correct common parent element. For example, in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/LLe98/) showing multiple different possible parent elements, depending how you group the anchors, on which line or lines do the "common parents" fall. If this example is too off topic, please make one that more clearly demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean to find

```
$('#parent').children().each(function(){
     var atag = $(this).find('a');
});
```

Here it finds all the `<a>` in `#parent`

if this is not what you want then please state in example what you what..

---

**Edited**
Does this help [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/7w8TC/57/)

Comment: To find all `<a>` tags within `#parent`, is as simple as:

`var atags = $('#parent a')`

I don't think this is what the OP is looking for, though

Comment: given a leaf node `<a>item1</a>` find all the other `<a>item2</a>` and etc, without knowing ahead of time the parent. I am looking for a way to traverse up from the `<a>item1</a>` and doing $(this).parent().find('a').notSelf() until all the items have been found.

Comment: @KimJongWoo so all the `<a>` has common parent `<div>` and all these `<div>` has a another common parent `<div>` this much fixed right?

Comment: yes I think you have the right idea. I think the algorithm is to look up the <a>item1</a>'s parent, and use that to `.find('a')`, if it only returns itself, repeat until we find the common parent.

Comment: something like `parent = $('a').eq(1).parent(); while (parent.find('a').get().size() == 1){parent = parent.parent();}return parent;`